# Issue with API Gateway-Lambda Integration: Consistent 504 Timeout Despite Quick Lambda Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've established a straightforward integration between API Gateway and Lambda. Upon invoking the gateway endpoint, I'm encountering an immediate 504 timeout after merely 1 second. This is evident in the logs, where API Gateway initiates the Lambda function call, and within 1 second, it returns with a timeout error.

Despite the rapid timeout, my Lambda function is indeed being invoked and performing its tasks, albeit well after the original request has received a 504 response. The Lambda function typically completes its execution within a maximum of 10 seconds, comfortably within the 29-second cap set by API Gateway.

What could be causing this discrepancy? Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The rapid timeout issue between API Gateway and Lambda despite the Lambda function completing within 10 seconds might be due to the API Gateway's timeout setting being lower than the Lambda execution time. You can adjust the API Gateway timeout setting to be higher than the Lambda execution time. I think that will resolve the issue.

Comment: As far as I know, the API Gateway timeout is by default set to 30 seconds and cannot be changed. I've looked several times because I keep thinking the same thing, but I can't find anything that says otherwise and there's no configuration option in the console. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table

Comment: Upon checking again, I found that the integration request resource within the API Gateway does have a custom timeout! So glad your comment pushed me to check it again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After checking again, the API Gateway timeout can be changed, you just can't update it to be below the lower bound or above the upper bound as per [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html).

To change the timeout, I needed to view the integration request resource within the API Gateway. From there, I was able to change the timeout. After a redeploy, it's now working as expected.